# How many physical CPU sockets can ubuntu desktop support?

Tags: cpu, motherboard

I was wondering how many cpu sockets Ubuntu would be able to support because im picking up a new server soon and would like to test some software on it, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Probably 8192 total cores. In practice this probably means that any single system you're able to buy over the counter without any software service included will work.

Run `grep NR_CPUS /boot/config-$(uname -r)` from a Ubuntu system with the relevant kernel version.

In practice it's not a factor I'd worry about for *normal* systems. If you're designing a supercomputer start thinking about it.